# How to randomly map a proportion of data value to a specific category?

Tags: python, random-seed, numpy-random

I have a dataset below which shows if a customer is a return customer or not. The end goal is for all returned customers, I need to map about 25% of them to 'yes 1 purchase' and 75% of them to 'yes >1 purchase'. I also need to set a seed to make sure the result does not change each time I re-run the process.

I researched on numpy random function and random seed function, but it seems they generate random numbers instead of randomly assign/map a proportion of data value to a specific category. Can anyone advise on how to do this?

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

list_customer_name = ['customer1','customer2','customer3','customer4','customer5',
'customer6','customer7','customer8','customer9','customer10','customer11','customer12',
'customer13','customer14','customer15','customer16','customer17','customer18']
list_return_customer = ['yes','yes','yes','yes','yes','yes',
'yes','yes','yes','yes','yes','yes','yes','yes',
'yes','yes','no','no']

df_test = pd.DataFrame({'customer_name': list_customer_name,
                    'return_customer?':list_return_customer})
```

data looks like this

[image]

desired output looks like this - 25% of customers (4 customer highlighted in yellow) flagged "yes" in the "return_customers?" column are mapped to "yes 1 purchase", the remaining 75% of customers (12 customers highlighted in green) are mapped to "yes >1 purchase".

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code seems to match your specifications:

```py
import random

import pandas as pd

random.seed(1234)

list_customer_name = ['customer1','customer2','customer3','customer4','customer5',
'customer6','customer7','customer8','customer9','customer10','customer11','customer12',
'customer13','customer14','customer15','customer16','customer17','customer18']

list_return_customer = ['yes','yes','yes','yes','yes','yes',
'yes','yes','yes','yes','yes','yes','yes','yes',
'yes','yes','no','no']

list_return_customer_final = ["yes >1 purchase" if status == "yes" else "no" for status in list_return_customer]

number_of_yes_1_purchase = 4

while number_of_yes_1_purchase > 0:
    rand_index = random.randint(0, len(list_return_customer_final) - 1)
    if list_return_customer_final[rand_index] == "yes 1 purchase" or list_return_customer_final[rand_index] == "no":
        continue
    list_return_customer_final[rand_index] = "yes 1 purchase"
    number_of_yes_1_purchase -= 1

df_test = pd.DataFrame({'customer_name': list_customer_name,
                        'return_customer?':list_return_customer,
                        'return_customer_final': list_return_customer_final})

print(df_test)
```

---

### Explanations:

I used the `random` module and set the seed to and arbitrary value with `random.seed(1234)`. Setting the seed allows random functions to behave the same every time we run the program.

I defined the number of "yes >1 purchase" to allocate with the variable `number_of_yes_1_purchase`. You can hardcode it or compute it depending on the length of `list_return_customer` (but remember to round the result to have an `int`).

With the `while` loop, I loop until I have allocated all of the "yes >1 purchase", so each time I allocate one I decrease the remaining number by one with `number_of_yes_1_purchase -= 1`

I used `rand_index = random.randint(0, len(list_return_customer_final) - 1)` to get a random index of the list to set to `"yes 1 purchase"`.
If this index is already a "yes 1 purchase" or a "no", I skip the current iteration with [`continue`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#break-and-continue-statements-and-else-clauses-on-loops).

The loop ends when `number_of_yes_1_purchase` reaches 0.

---

If you have any questions, don't hesitate to ask

Comment: Thanks for this solution and the detailed explanation. As you pointed out, the number_of_yes_1_purchase is hard coded to 4 (which is the exact 25% of the returned customer population). My real dataset contains a lot more customers and the numbers are always changing. Is there a simple way or more dynamic way to achieve this? Either way, your solution is great.

Comment: Yes, you could do something like `number_of_yes_1_purchase = round(len(list_customer_name) * 0.25)`. 0.25 is the percentage, and `round()` is used to get a whole number.

Comment: Do you mind explaining what does the If statement and the following continue do?

Comment: also what does number_of_yes_1_purchase -= 1 do?

Comment: I edited my post to try and explain better

Comment: `number_of_yes_1_purchase -= 1` is equivalent to `number_of_yes_1_purchase += -1` and `number_of_yes_1_purchase = number_of_yes_1_purchase + 1`

Comment: Thanks a lot for the explanation. Greatly appreciated for your helps and insights.